# How to get the instance ninject passes into a constructor

Tags: c#, singleton, ninject

I don't understand this behaviour of ninject singletons. Here's a simple example.

```
void Main()
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IB>().To<B>().InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<B>().To<B>().InSingletonScope();

    C c = kernel.Get<C>();
    B b = kernel.Get<B>();
    B b2 = kernel.Get<B>();

    ReferenceEquals(c.b, b); //false
    ReferenceEquals(b, b2); //true
}

public interface IB
{ }

public class B : IB
{ }

public class C
{
    public IB b;
    public C(IB b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `ReferenceEquals(c.b, b)` returns false.

I'd have assumed that if I declare an object as a singleton then ninject would use only a single instance of that object but that appears to not be the case.

Based on my testing it appears to use one instance for constructor injection, and one instance to return to me when I call `kernel.Get`.

What I'd like is for `kernel.Get` to return to me the same instance that was used for constructor injection. Is this possible?

Comment: The types `B` and `IB` are different and you create two different bindings so you have two singletons `B` and `IB` which are resolved to instances of type `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `C` depends on `IB`, not `B`.

If you do something like this:

```
IB ib = kernel.Get<IB>();
```

And compare that with c.b like this:

```
var eq = ReferenceEquals(c.b, ib);
```

You would get `true`.

Each registration that you did (`B` and `IB`) give you a different singleton.

If you want to have the same singleton, you can do a single registration like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IB,B>().To<B>().InSingletonScope();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved my own question.

It's because I'm calling `kernel.Get` on `B` not `IB`

```
void Main()
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IB>().To<B>().InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<B>().To<B>().InSingletonScope();

    C c = kernel.Get<C>();
    B b = kernel.Get<B>();
    B b2 = kernel.Get<B>();
    IB b3 = kernel.Get<IB>();

    ReferenceEquals(c.b, b); //false
    ReferenceEquals(c.b, b3); //true
    ReferenceEquals(b, b2); //true
}
```